# Perché si dice "pandemia DA coronavirus"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Why do we say "pandemia DA coronavirus" and not "pandemia DI coronavirus"?

PS: I have read extensively about the two prepositions and no case of what I have come across explains the usage of DA in this sentence.

Comment: @Charo, I mean that I could say "il mal di mare" but "pandemia da coronavirus"! Why? Why can't I say "pandemia di coronavirus"?

Comment: This also seems surprising to me because you can find, for instance, [here](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/03/12/definizione-pandemia-differenza-epidemia/), the expression "epidemia di COVID-19", but, for example, [here](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/03/20/origine-significato-lockdown-pandemie/) or [here](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2015/07/30/suffissoidi-inglesi-mageddon-pocalypse/), "pandemia da COVID-19". So, it's a very interesting question.

Comment: It could be a tacit "causata": pandemia [causata] da coronavirus.

Comment: Maybe it can be said both ways? With "pandemia da COVID-19" meaning "pandemia causata dalla COVID-19" and "pandemia di COVID-19" meaning "pandemia della malattia chiamata COVID-19"?

Comment: @Charo, molto interessante! Grazie per la tua spiegazione!

Comment: @user11731289:  Non ne sono completamente sicura: sarebbe utile che un italiano madrelingua confermasse quanto ho detto.

Comment: And maybe the point is that "coronavirus" is the virus. Well, in fact it's a family of viruses that includes SARS-CoV-2, the virus that causes the disease called COVID-19. So you can have a pandemic of a certain disease or caused by a certain disease. But the pandemic is *caused by* a virus, it's not a "pandemic of a virus".

Comment: @Charo, yeah indeed possible!!  both of your explanations are interesting. Let us hope for some native speaker to shed some more light on the matter.

Comment: Yes, it's *epidemia di influenza* (because *influenza* is the disease). Instead, *coronavirus* is the cause of the pandemic, so *pandemia da coronavirus* or *pandemia di covid-19*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't say *pandemia di coronavirus*, because *pandemia* can have as a specification the name of a disease. The name of the disease is *covid-19*, so we can say either

> pandemia di covid-19

or

> pandemia da coronavirus

The virus is the cause of the pandemic, not the effect, hence *da*. Similarly, it's *epidemia di influenza, di vaiolo, di Ebola*. We can't say *epidemia da influenza*. It could be *epidemia da Ebola* if we think to *Ebola* as the name of the virus.

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: However, as I have said in a comment, I have seen both "pandemia" (and "epidemia") "da COVID-19" and "di COVID-19".

Comment: @Charo People need not know that “covid-19” is the name of the disease. There's great confusion about the topic. Many people don't even know what a virus is, by the way.

Comment: OK, @egreg, but it seems strange to me that "pandemia da COVID-19" appears in [this blog about language](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2015/07/30/suffissoidi-inglesi-mageddon-pocalypse/), in which, I believe, they are very careful to write well and in which it's explained that  [COVID-19 is the disease and not the virus](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/).

Comment: @Charo I see it only in added images, one from the DPCM (decreto del presidente del consiglio dei ministri): I reject considering bureaucrats as a reliable source for language. ;-) There is no occurrence of “pandemia” in the text.

Comment: @egreg: I was referring to this sentence: "Aggiornamento marzo 2020 – L’elemento – *(a)geddon* si ritrova anche in coronageddon, neologismo usato su Twitter e altri social per descrivere la pandemia da COVID-19".

Comment: @Charo Wrong usage. Complain. ;-)

Comment: @egreg:  It appears also [here](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/03/20/origine-significato-lockdown-pandemie/): "Il Portale linguistico del Canada ha pubblicato *Glossary on the COVID-19 pandemic*, un glossario bilingue in inglese e francese rivolto a comunicatori e traduttori con lo scopo di garantire una comunicazione corretta, efficiente e comprensibile sulla pandemia da COVID-19". Maybe it's really a wrong usage of preposition "da", but I'm not completely sure about that.

Comment: @Charo Well, If I google for the literal `"epidemia da vaiolo"`, I get eight results. This should clear things up, doesn't it?